# IText7 - Force Table to continue on new Page when creating table (C#)

Tags: c#, itext7

I'm currently working on creating invoices with itext7 and using tables. Each product can have multiple versions but I only put the version if the customer took at least one item of the specified version.
My invoice should look something like this:
Article A (8 total)

- Version 1 (3)
- Version 2 (5)

Article B (3 total)

- Version 2 (3)

At my current version the table gets broken to the next page whenever the next line doesn't fit on the current page. Is there a way to ensure that the lines of each article stay together and I can insert the page break manually in my table so it continues to the next page?
I've tried adding an AreaBreak and a new Page so far but that only produced empty pages at the end of the document. Further I've tried to put each article as a nested table but that didn't help either.